# What is the replacement for sandbox command in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I made an addon for chrome in which's manifest file I used sandbox command. Sandbox command doesn't work in firefox. Is there any command similar or same as sandbox command for manifest.json file that would work with firefox?

Firefox accepts:

```
"content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self'; object-src"
```

but it's not functioning like sandbox in chrome.

I have tried

```
"content_security_policy":"sandbox"
```

and

```
"content_security_policy":"sandbox 'allow-scripts'"
```

and almost everything from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/sandbox  and here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP.

HTML file:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
      <p class="text-light" id="something">text<br><br><br><br></p>
      <button onclick="function1()" class="btn button-gradient">click 
      me</button>
</body>
</html>


<script>...</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Manifest file:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy":
        "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self'; object-src",

  "description": "description" ,
  "homepage_url": "...",


  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],




  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "title",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }


}
```

For chrome I just used:

```
 "sandbox": {
 "pages": [
   "page1.html"
 ]
}
```

For javascript script in html, but that is not working for firefox...

Comment: Your CSP is sandboxing the entire extension which makes no sense generally because an extension is already a privileged secure context by default. This might explain why Firefox didn't even implement it. What is the goal here? If you want to use inline onclick handlers, see [onClick within Chrome Extension not working](//stackoverflow.com/a/25721457). If you want to imitate the "sandbox" manifest key in Firefox, there may be an existing answer for that or a ticket on https://bugzil.la. Off the top of my head I can only think of embedding an actual sandboxed iframe.

Comment: Thank you so much @wOxxOm! It was sandboxed iframe, but now there is another problem, I created new html file in which I added sandboxed iframe which has allow-scripts argument with html source file which is already mentioned here. Now, when I add allow-same-origin argument(because i want same css file applied to iframe and main html file ) script is not working anymore. If you know how to resolve this please do help!